# Ubuntu will not automatically boot from SSD

Tags: boot, bios

I have both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a boot loader installed on my SSD. My SSD is not showing up as option to automatically boot from in the BIOS in my boot load order; however I can manually boot from it in the BIOS.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your SSD is external, as is mine.  I should add that if that is the case, most readers here will not understand that.  Some bioses have that issue.  My asus is one fine example of this.  On my asus, I need to press esc every time it boots to bring up the boot selection method.  It takes just a little getting use to, but is worth it.

Comment: My SSD is internally connected

Comment: I see.  In that case the boot selection is not to be configured in your bios, but using a different utility which can modify the boot sequence in your boot loader.  I have done this several times but stopped when I discovered I could also crash my boot loader.  You may wish to google around for the answere.  I would do it for you now but it is late and I am tired.

Answer (score 0):

If BIOS can boot to it manually it [*almost* certainly] can boot to it automatically. It's just a case of working out what needs kicking. Many motherboards have multiple disk controllers (with some being third party that get a much lower boot priority). It might be worth moving to another controller if you can and seeing if that allows you to select the correct drive.

Anyway, failing that and as a very distant workaround, you could install Grub (the bootloader) onto other devices... [Like a small USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/10632/449). Then make that the bootable device.

But seriously, I'd take this up with the Motherboard/SSD manufacturers before getting that far.

Comment: I switched the SATA cables between my HDD and SSD, it didn't do anything. This suggests that the SSD is unbootable for some reason.

Comment: I just checked in the `Disks` application, and it says that my SSD is bootable. Strange...