# Regarding usb installation on usb drive

Tags: system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my 16 gb usb drive.When i connect it to my laptop it boot properly and i can use,update and install any package on usb drive.But when i connect to other computer it cant boot.

Comment: Check this: [How to install grub on usb flash drive?](http://askubuntu.com/q/10571)

Comment: What does mean «can't boot»? Does it show errors, black screen, or a BIOS message «No operating system found»? Also, note: USB sticks usually have reeealy slow IO, so to have a usable system you'd need to move `/var/log` to tmpfs, and disable *atime*. That's a bare minimum I recall, there's probably more could be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install grub on usb flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10571/how-to-install-grub-on-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact the bootloader was installed to the hard drive of the system and not to the usb. 
Open a terminal, and type `sudo fdisk -l` (your USB flash drive should show up in the list if it is inserted). Now, type `sudo grub-install /dev/<insert usb drive name here>` to install it on your usb drive.

for example:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/ubuntuusb
```

If you labelled your usb device ubuntuusb.
Be careful to select the right device or you could inadvertantly destroy another operating systems bootloader. 
Hope this helps.