# How do I install Ubuntu to my hard drive and use a flash drive to boot it?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 16.04, ubuntu-mate

My current computer has Neverware CloudReady and I want to dual-boot it with Ubuntu MATE. The problem is that CloudReady makes around 30 different partitions as shown here:
[image: Too many partitions]
I *do* know that the last partition holds the user's files. So I decided to install Ubuntu MATE on another partition but use a spare flash drive to boot it. So, whenever I boot from the flash drive, Ubuntu MATE shows up and when I boot normally CloudReady shows up. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is install the grub bootloader (or an alternative bootloader) on the flash drive. I've personally never done this before but take a look at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10571/how-to-install-grub-on-usb-flash-drive).
Alternatively, if you know the partition that contains the Neverware CloudReady bootloader you might be able to install grub on that same partition giving you the option to dual boot and select an OS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: However, this flash drive is currently being used as the Ubuntu MATE installation disk. So will I have to use a different flash drive to install the OS first?

Comment: That's correct! Alternatively, you could use a DVD or hard drive as the installation disc.

Comment: I don't have other installation media, so I installed using the -b ubiquity switch to not install a bootloader. What do I do now?

Comment: Now you need to install grub (the bootloader) on the flash drive and edit the grub configuration on the flash drive to point to the partition on your internal hard drive. Was the link I provided in my answer not helpful? If so, what step are you stuck at?

Comment: I tried to install grub on the flash drive using the LiveUSB (sudo grub-install /dev/sdb), but I get the error `grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.`  I don't know what to do now.