# Impossible to Install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 from a USB drive using NTFS?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, usb-drive, ntfs, rufus

I have a new computer with no disk drive and a Windows 10 (NTFS) partition, and I wanted to install Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot configuration from a USB boot drive (exactly as I have done before for 16.04 on a Windows 7 (FAT32) machine). I followed several instructions (e.g. [How to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031993/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows-10)) which recommend using Rufus 3.8, which does the job if I keep the default file system (FAT32), however when the installation comes to the screen for choosing Installation type there are no options. This appears to be because the installer cannot recognize the existing Windows NTFS partition.

On the other hand, if I specify an NTFS file system in Rufus, then it creates two partitions on the USB drive (one FAT and one NTFS) and gets stuck in grub without progressing to the installation options, regardless of which USB partition I prioritize in the boot menu. I tried some tips for getting out of grub, but "exit" is all that works, and the system resorts to Windows.

I have tried other USB formatting tools, but with less luck. I have disabled Secure Boot in the menu, and I have disabled hibernation completely. The only hint I have is snapping some lines that come up, for about 0.5 sec., just before the grub prompt takes over.  These seem to be talking about detecting and then disconnecting an existing NTFS system. It seems that what I am trying to do should be straightforward, but I am beginning to doubt whether it is possible at all.  Perhaps the Rufus developer, Akeo, could respond, as he mentioned that he had managed this about 18 months ago: [How to make a live USB - WITHOUT FAT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060975/how-to-make-a-live-usb-without-fat).

Comment: Did you try " something else " option during installation process from USB drive ?

Comment: Thanks - I'll try those, and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user68186: the second solution offered in that link (originally from http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/) worked like a charm (with the FAT32 file format set in Rufus). Essentially if your hard drive has been configured to use the RAID SATA mode, then the Ubuntu installer cannot see the Windows partition.  Switching from RAID to AHCI in the BIOS setup (when booting) solves this. First putting Windows into the minimal safe-boot configuration is a safety measure (I used msconfig for this), one can revert afterwards. I tried putting the SATA mode back to RAID afterwards as well, but that was a bad idea.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, and you posted your own answer to your question. You should accept your own answer as correct and put the green check mark on it. I am still voting to close this question as a duplicate to the other question.

Comment: The tick mark is greyed out.  It says that I have to wait another 7 hours before I can accept my own answer (though really I am accepting heynnema's answer).

Comment: Indeed the system makes you wait for some hours. Since your question has been marked as a duplicate, you don't have to (if you don't want) mark your answer as correct. The notice at the top will send other users to the old question and answer by heynnema.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to try and help this situation but I want to make sure I have all details first. Correct me if I'm wrong or insure that I have it correct please.
Your computer does not have a cd,DVD, or blu-ray drive
You currently have Windows OS installed and working on SSD or hdd
It really seems you are wanting both on usb, but from my experience Windows tried very hard to make it so you can not install it on anything connected by a USB.
I currently run duel boot Ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10. Installed on SSD.

Comment: Yes, that is about right.  I have Windows on the SSD, and made 500GB of un-allocated space to prepare for the Linux system.  I do not want to touch the Windows system, and I do not want to buy an external CD ROM just for this installation; mainly because I see no reason why it wouldn't have exactly the same problem as the USB stick.  Which version of 18.04 are you on, and which application did you use to make the boot drive?

Comment: I found it easier to install Linux first, then Windows. But if that's not an option install Ubuntu by booting as a live cd/usb. If your not familiar I will explain more on that later if needed. Then boot from USB by either changing boot option in bios or  by hitting I believe f12 during boot when prompted. Follow the directions to install, KEEPING WINDOWS make sure not to click on format entire ssd. This way should allow everything to go smoothly. This is assuming the 500gb empty space is not formatted at all . If it is formatted you should be able to access it via Windows to remove format.

Comment: Alternatively, you could boot from USB using gparted which is helpful in fixing partitions to your liking. https://gparted.org/liveusb.php